# MCT, DCT, and Fatou's Lemma related problems Bank

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

One of my friends is preparing for his Analysis Ph.D. comprehensive exam. He requested me to give him a list of problems that can be solved using the three standard convergence theorems namely MCT, DCT, and FL. I have already collected some problems from some standard textbooks. Can you please recommend me more problems? I think it will be helpful for many other students.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It would be helpful if you listed all the textbooks you sifted through.

Comment: I've collected some problems from the Books written by the following authors.  1. Royden, 2. Wheeden, 3. Richard F. Bass ( this one is written mostly for Ph.D. qualifiers), 4. Tao's Measure Theory Book. BTW, I have not collected any problem from Rudin, and Folland.

Comment: I recomend these splended notes of my professor :http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~papadim/measure_theory.pdf...Also DE Barra's Book :Measure Theory and Integration, has many interesting problems...Also i recommend Gelbaum's :Problems in real and complex analysis..this is a problem workbook

Comment: Thank you very much.